Is mathematical Platonism necessary for mathematical truths/knowledge to be non-empirical?
There is already a question about whether mathematical truth is empirical: Is mathematical truth empirical?. The most upvoted answer asserts it is not:

Mathematics is not empirical: A mathematical proof is independent from any experience. It only relies on the correct application of the usual or a refined logic. To check new and original ideas on a field which is well-specified by precise definitions and axioms.
If someone considers mathematics to be an empirical science, it would be interesting to hear the arguments for this objection.

Similarly, a different answer to a related question asserts the same:

Claims that make no assertions or predictions about the world can be assessed without resort to empirical evidence.
For example, claims about what conclusions follow from mathematical axioms can be evaluated based on logical proofs, without resort to empirical evidence.

That said, experimental mathematics is an actual field:

Experimental mathematics is an approach to mathematics in which computation is used to investigate mathematical objects and identify properties and patterns. It has been defined as "that branch of mathematics that concerns itself ultimately with the codification and transmission of insights within the mathematical community through the use of experimental (in either the Galilean, Baconian, Aristotelian or Kantian sense) exploration of conjectures and more informal beliefs and a careful analysis of the data acquired in this pursuit."

If the terms experimental and empirical are considered synonymous, then at least part of mathematics could be seen as empirical. However, this does not imply that all of mathematics is empirical or experimental necessarily. There might be a valid dichotomy between empirical and non-empirical mathematics. So my question pertains to the latter: Would these non-empirical mathematical truths exist in some sort of Platonic realm? In other words, is mathematical Platonism a necessary condition for (at least some) mathematical truths to be non-empirical?

NOTE: Answers should ideally carefully explain how they understand terms like experimental, empirical, non-experimental, non-empirical, as well as abstract, concrete, a priori, a posteriori, and any other relevant terms as they see fit. I'm open to considering different definitions and learning from different perspectives (instead of imposing my own definitions). Personally, it's hard for me to grasp how non-empirical mathematical knowledge could possible without Platonism, but I'm happy to hear other perspectives either confirming that view or challenging it.

Non-empirical=A priori? Innateness or intuition without experimental date does necessarily imply "seeing" into the Platonic realm? Issues still debated...

The form of "experimental mathematics" described is not empirical. It is just a way to automate the discovery of theorems, which remain non-empirical.

@DavidGudeman Would you like to explain how in an answer?

Experimental math means automated generation of candidate equations or theorems and automated checking of candidate equations. This has nothing whatsoever to do with the fact that mathematical proofs do not rely on empirical evidence. So, "experimental" and "empirical" in this context are unrelated. You might as well start asking questions like: Did God really not create the natural numbers? Or: Is it conceivable that God created the natural numbers, but did not create the imaginary ones? Those kind of questions would have at least as much sense (if not more) than the OPs question.

@mudskipper "This has nothing whatsoever to do with the fact that mathematical proofs do not rely on empirical evidence.  So, "experimental" and "empirical" in this context are unrelated." - And what is the justification for this claim? You just asserted that they are different without offering any justification.

Comments are not meant for discussion. Please follow any undergraduate math course -- or read a serious book, e.g. Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries by Marvin J. Greenberg, which even smart high-schoolers should be able to work through -- before engaging in armchair philosophy about "the nature of math".

@mudskipper Can you point me to the specific page and quote from any of those books supporting your claim that experimental and empirical are unrelated here?

Necessary: I would say no. There are supporters of the view that math knowledge is a priori that are not Platonists. And Plato asserted the existence of non-physical objects, included nymbers, whose knowledge is innate, but there is no a priori in Plato.

@user80226 - Why would I do that?

@mudskipper You don't have to. You are free to do whatever you want with your life. But there is nothing wrong in asking.

@user80226 - I kind of fail to see what in any way motivates you in asking these questions. It's like saying: Let's have a discussion about how to design a better toilet, without ever having looked in detail at plumbing systems (or human anatomy). If you're interested in what "experimental math" actual means - then by all means, dive in, and read some books, study it, see what the Ramanujan machine project actually has achieved and how it works for instance.

@mudskipper I'm not asking how to do experimental math research, I'm asking what's the nature of mathematical knowledge, metaphysically speaking. Studying the Ramanujan machine project would not be helpful toward that end. It's just software. Software is physical, and runs on hardware, which is physical. So it would only confirm that this is all physical, experimental, and empirical.

@user80226 - Indeed, and I'm saying without studying the things you supposedly want to talk about, you can not know what you're talking about.

@mudskipper this may be of interest, particularly the last reply.

@user80226 - ChatGPT is pretty good, isn't it. It even detects subtle emotional tones based on brief comments.


Platonism in mathematics means that mathematical theorems hold independently from the work of mathematicians.
Mathematical truth
are non-empirical means that one does not - and even cannot - rely
on empirical means to prove them.
The concept of Platonism is from
ontology, the non-empirical character of mathematical truth is from
epistemology. You ask whether the epistemology presupposes a
certain ontology.

I do not see any argument for the view, that the mathematical tools developed during
the history of mathematics like number-theory, ideal-theory, Galois
theory,…, arithmetic schemes already exist since billions of years
and belong to the “blueprint of the universe”.
In addition, there was a long
discussion on this blog whether mathematical truth is non-empirical,
see here. I take it as granted that mathematical truth is
non-empirical.

IMO mathematical concepts have been invented by mathematicians. And
subsequently mathematicians have discovered which statements are
true in this these disciplines and which are not. First the invention,
subsequently the discovery. The field of mathematics was built by
mathematicians and further explored by successors.
This fact supports the view that Platonism is not necessary for the non-empirical character of mathematical truths.


